# Get value of a textfield on focus out

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I get the value from a textfield on focus out. Let's say I have a textfield. I type something and click somewhere outside. I need to get the value from textfield. I only see onChanged property in the documentation which would store each time when a character is added to the textfield which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this codepen https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/MZqoWo can help you. The `onBlur` prop exists on `TextFiled`. It's prop interface `ITextFieldProps` is extending from `React.AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>` so all `input` native props are present on `TextField` even if it's not obvious right away.

To grab the value on the other side you could use the getter method `value` through the `componentRef` prop or access the `event.target.value` in the `onBlur` callback. Both are shown in the codepen.